# Laravel + Artdarek OAuth

Tags: oauth, laravel

I have few route requiring Authentication in Laravel 4:

Route::get('/login', array('uses' => 'Login@show'));

//Routes requiring authentication
Route::get('/private', array('before' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'Private@showPage'));

When I try to access /private, I get redirected to /login ( Not sure where that URL comes from ). Since this was giving me an error, I tried to create a route /login... which doesn't help since the error is:

```
ReflectionException
Class Login does not exist
```

I believe the problem is that Laravel believe I'm using the default Authentication mechanism, but I installed Artdarek OAuth ( https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel#installation )

How can I make sure the `'before' => 'auth'` command will check the authentication with the OAuth module and not with the default authentication thing (that doesn't seem to have a working skeleton implemented in my case anyway :( ).

Thanks.

Comment: I'm at the point where I just removed the Auth thing and will simply use another mean for securing my pages so I'm sure the default Auth mechanism is not used.